# Least Upper Bound of Rational Numbers

Tags: real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

I'm trying to work out a question of a past exam, but I can't seem to figure it out. If I could get some help, I would be very appreciative. The question is:

When we use the definition of real numbers as sets of rational numbers, the supremum of a set $A$ of numbers is defined as the number corresponding to the union of the corresponding sets.  Specifically, if we write $\alpha_x$ for the set of rational numbers which corresponds to $x\in A$, then $\sup A$ is the number of corresponding to the set $\cup_{x\in A} \alpha_x$.  Show that $\sup A$ defined in this way is indeed the least upper bound of the numbers in $A$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it Dedekind Cut Day or something? :-)

Comment: Briefly, you need to show that all rationals that are less than $\sup A$ are in the union of the Dedekind cuts, and that none of the rationals that are greater than or equal to $\sup A$ are in that union.  Are you able to do that?

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to separate the rationals from the $\sup A$.  How can I tell which rationals are which?  This question was worth $\frac{10}{100}$ marks.

Comment: Showing that no rationals greater than or equal to $\sup A$ is in the union is pretty straightforward: If $x \geq \sup A$, then for any of the numbers $z \in A$, $x \geq z$, and then $x$ cannot be in the Dedekind cut for $z$.  Since this is true for all $z \in A$, $x$ cannot be in the union of the Dedekind cuts.

Comment: To show that all rationals less than $\sup A$ are in the union of the Dedekind cuts, I would proceed by contradiction.  Suppose there was a rational $x < \sup A$ that was not in the union.  Then by the density of the rationals, there must be a rational value $y$ such that $x < y < \sup A$.  Is $y$ in the union?  It cannot be, because $x < y$ and $y$ is not in the union.  But if it is not in the union, then $y$ represents an upper bound to $A$ that is less than the supposed $\sup A$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: What is the set of rationals that corresponds to x?